# What word can I use for a group of people sharing stories with each other?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a single word that describes a *group of people sitting together and sharing their life stories with each other*. But it doesn't have to be stories about their lives. It could also be just stories about anything.

Is there any (close) single word or phrase or a better way to express this?

Comment: Story swappers?

Comment: What context do you need it for? Because from the sound if it "group of people sharing stories" sounds nice enough.

Comment: This amounts to a *support* group, once called a consciousness raising group.

Comment: Fireside chat (although [Roosevelt's already stolen that one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fireside_chats)), Mother's meeting (if it wasn't so gender-specific).

Comment: @YosefBaskin, that implies they are doing it with the end of psychological support, rather than just passing the time as old friends (granted, the OP doesn't specify)

Comment: If you want meaningless chatter, there's shooting the breeze, chewing the fat, jawboning.

Comment: Allude to [Canterbury Tales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Canterbury_Tales).

Comment: @YosefBaskin "...shooting the breez, chewing the fat, jawboning." All can be done ad nauseam at Katz's delicatessen in New York. Very enjoyable!

Comment: Hi Javiator. Can you please add a sample sentence? Based on the comments and answers posted, it's not clear whether you're looking for a noun to describe the participants, a noun to describe the event, or a verb to describe what happens, etc.

Comment: I am looking for a noun to describe the event

Comment: This is a little bit of a stretch, but there's "gam", which described the socializing (and story-telling) that occurred when whaling-ships met at sea.

Answer (score 0):

One subset (depending on the type of story) would be

> **Gossiper**
>
> **gossip**
> [gos-uh p]
> /noun
>
> 1. idle talk or rumor, especially about the personal or private affairs of others.
> 2. light, familiar talk or writing.
> 3. Also, gossiper, gossipper. a person given to tattling or idle talk.

or

> **Yenta**
> [yen-tuh]
> /noun, Slang.
>
> 1. a person, especially a woman, who is a busybody or gossip.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite right, but ***[coffee klatch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coffee+klatch).***

In a coffee klatch, people (usually women) will talk about anything and everything, from trivial to as serious as can be.  Can this be extended to a conversation over beer, or wine, or mead and whatever people drank around the fire tens of thousands of years ago, when people got together and forged myths to explain creation and the workings of the gods in daily life and to plan the details of tomorrow's bison hunt?

Answer (score -1):

While I see that your question includes a more general request for a term, I can only think of terms that refer to subsets of the request.

> **Reminisce**
> [rem-uh-nis]
> /verb (used without object), reminisced, reminiscing.
>
> 1. to recall past experiences, events, etc.; indulge in reminiscence.

This term refers to the activity, and not the group. I have not encountered the noun form in use before. However, I have seen some dictionaries include "reminiscer" to describe the person doing the action, so the group could be called "reminiscers".